# Efficient Computation of The Least Fixed Point of A Polynomial

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

Let P(x) denote the polynomial in question. The least fixed point (LFP) of P is the lowest value of x such that x=P(x). The polynomial has real coefficients. There is no guarantee in general that an LFP will exist, although one is guaranteed to exist if the degree is odd and ≥ 3. I know of an efficient solution if the degree is 3. x=P(x) thus 0=P(x)-x. There is a closed-form cubic formula, solving for x is somewhat trivial and can be hardcoded. Degrees 2 and 1 are similarly easy. It's the more complicated cases that I'm having trouble with, since I can't seem to come up with a good algorithm for arbitrary degree.

EDIT:

I'm only considering real fixed points and taking the least among them, not necessarily the fixed point with the least absolute value.

Comment: By "least", do you mean in absolute value?

Comment: i think this belongs to theorotical computer science stack

Comment: Are you restricted to polynomials? Finding the roots of arbitrary functions is non-trivial, but I think there are good solutions for general polynomials.

Comment: @Suraj Chandran: This is not theoretical computer science.

Comment: @PengOne No. I'm only considering real fixed points and taking the least among them.

Comment: @Gregory: Okay, then -1000 is smaller than 2, right? Then just use the rule of signs as I suggest below to isolate the final crossing of the x-axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want the least fixed point, you can't get away without finding all real roots of P(x) - x and selecting the smallest.

Finding all the roots of a polynomial is a *tricky subject*. If you have a black box routine, then by all means use it. Otherwise, consider the following trick:

- Form M the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of P(x) - x
- Find all eigenvalues of M

but this requires you have access to a routine for finding eigenvalues (which is another tricky problem, but there are plenty of good libraries).

Otherwise, you can implement the [Jenkins-Traub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm) algorithm, which is a highly non trivial piece of code.

I don't really recommend finding a zero (with eg. Newton's method) and [deflating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) until you reach degree one: it is very unstable if not done properly, and you'll lose a lot of accuracy (and it is very difficult to tackle multiple roots with it). The proper way do do it is in fact the above-mentioned Jenkins-Traub algorithm.

Comment: "I don't really recommend finding a zero (with eg. Newton's method) and deflating until you reach degree one it is very unstable if not done properly, and you'll lose a lot of accuracy"

I understand that this would be the case if a polynomial is a black box, but I don't understand why root-finding procedure + polynomial division is a poor idea if you can examine the definition of the polynomial with ease (say it's stored as a list of reals). It is my understanding that Newton's method has very quick convergence etc. I don't doubt what you're saying, but I'm having trouble understanding  why.

Comment: @Gregory: deflation is unstable, and the procedure loses accuracy. Even for moderate degree polynomials, you'll lose enough accuracy to find wrong / nonexistent roots. Also, finding multiple roots with Newton method is bound to fail: (x - a)^n is approximately epsilon^n when |x - a| ~ epsilon, so you'll only get a to the nth root of machine precision. Deflating by x - a will give you an imprecise list of coefficients. Polynomial roots can be very sensitive to the coefficients (even if they are a continuous function of them).

Comment: You can have a look at Numerical Recipes for some guidelines about this problem too (and also on how to alleviate the deflation problem).

Answer (score 6):

Just solve `f(x) = P(x) - x` using your favorite numerical method. For example, you could iterate

```
x_{n + 1} = x_n - P(x_n) / (P'(x_n) - 1).
```

You won't find closed-form formula in general because [there aren't any closed-form formula for quintic and higher polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Application_to_classical_problems). Thus, for quintic and higher degree you *have* to use a numerical method of some sort.

Comment: but how does that guarantee finding the least fixed point? It isn't enough to find an arbitrary one.

Comment: You will need to find all the zeros and pick the smallest. This is non-trivial, since you have to determine how many zeros are complex.

Comment: @Greogry Nisbet: It doesn't. But once you find one, say `p`, you can run some root-finding method that searches for roots in `(-p, p)`.

Comment: Least doesn't mean "least absolute value".

Comment: @Gregory Nisbet: Oh, so you want the smallest real fixed point?

Comment: @Jason: Yes. I'm sorry that wasn't clear from the start. Also, the fixed point with the least absolute value isn't guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is trying to find the "least" (here I'm not sure if you mean in magnitude or actually the smallest, which could be the most negative) root of a polynomial. There is no closed form solution for polynomials of large degree, but there are myriad numerical approaches to finding roots.

As is often the case, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) is a good place to begin your search.

If you want to find the smallest root, then you can use the [rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to pin down the interval where it exists and then use some numerical method to find roots in that interval.